# Lightning v.body array becomes unrenderable when processed in JS controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

When I try to take the elements from inside the `v.body` attribute of my Lightning Component and put them into another structure (e.g. a 2D array, or an Object), they seem to get mangled to the wrong type and don't display correctly. Is there some way around this?

Here's an example app I built to test the behaviour:

TestContainer.cmp

```
<aura:component description="TestContainer">
    <aura:attribute name="body2D" type="Object[]" access="private" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <lightning:card title="From v.body">
        <aura:iteration var="thisBodyItem" items="{!v.body}">
            {!thisBodyItem}
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:card>

    <lightning:card title="From 2D array, v.body2D">
        <aura:iteration var="bodyRow" items="{!v.body2D}">
            <aura:iteration var="thisBodyItem" items="{!bodyRow}">
                {!thisBodyItem}
            </aura:iteration>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:card>

    <lightning:card title="From 2D array, via TestContainerRow">
        <aura:iteration var="bodyRow" items="{!v.body2D}">
           <c:TestContainerRow bodyRow="{!bodyRow}" />
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:card>

</aura:component>
```

TestContainerController.js:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var body = component.get('v.body');
        var body2D = [[]];
        body.forEach(function (thisBodyItem) {
            body2D[0].push(thisBodyItem);
        })
        component.set('v.body2D', body2D);
    }
})
```

TestContainerRow.cmp:

```
<aura:component description="TestContainerRow">
    <aura:attribute name="bodyRow" type="Object[]" access="public" />

    <aura:iteration var="thisBodyItem" items="{!v.bodyRow}">
        {!thisBodyItem}
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

And finally, the app, TestContainerApp.app:

```
<aura:application description="TestContainerApp">

    <c:TestContainer>
        <ui:message title="foo" severity="info"/>
    </c:TestContainer>

</aura:application>
```

What we're doing is passing a `<ui:message>` in as the single item in the body array for the `<c:TestContainer>`. Then displaying it in various ways:

- First by a normal `<aura:iteration>` which works as expected
- Second by stuffing the body into a 2D array and 2 levels of `<aura:iteration>` which prints `SecureComponentRef: markup://ui:message {4:0}{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }` instead of the actual `<ui:message>`
- Third, I tried going via the `<c:TestContainerRow>` which encapsulates a row

Some things along the way:

- I was not able to declare the `body2D` attribute as `Aura.Component[][]` which is what it should be. This gives a save-error, so it had to be `Object[]`
- I was not able to declare bodyRow in `<c:TestContainerRow>` as `Aura.Component[]`, this gives a runtime error:

> Component.createComponentStack: invalid config. Expected component
>   definition, found 'SecureComponentRef: markup://ui:message {4:0}{ key:
>   {"namespace":"c"} }'.
>       Failing descriptor: {aura:iteration}

There are numerous applications where this would be useful e.g. displaying a list of components with some extra metadata associated with them, it would be nice to have the JS controller make a list of objects which contain the component and the metadata together. Or, in my case, displaying the list of components in a table where I cannot use a flexbox-based solution like `<lightning:layout>`

Comment: FWIW, I added this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TujtQAC) to suggest that Salesforce give us an attribute called "data" that we can use to attach custom data to system components, which it seems would solve at least one of your use cases.

Comment: Thanks - I saw that idea via twitter. I think the argument against it on performance reasons is pretty strong, though. Lightning is slow enough already!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the performance isn't nearly as bad as they think it'll be. I'm setting up a copy of aura to test it out, but I have to do this in a VM, since Aura doesn't support Windows...